# Can't load options with Select.Async

Tags: react-select

I can't get the basic application with async options loading to work. The `getOptions` function gets called but the select control doesn't display them. Here's the code and Plunkr link https://plnkr.co/edit/vKZXhjQRhDWflMQpt8b5?p=preview

```
var options = [
    { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
    { value: 'two', label: 'Two' }
];

function logChange(val) {
    console.log("Selected: " + JSON.stringify(val));
}

function getOptions(input) {
  console.log(input)
  return Promise.resolve(options)
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Select.Async
    name="form-field-name"
    value="one"
    loadOptions={getOptions}
    onChange={logChange}
  />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is return { options: yourDataArray } instead of yourDataArray.

For example, in your code, `return Promise.resolve(options)` should be changed to `return Promise.resolve({options})`

Hope this helps.